# Installing MySQL 5.7 on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows-10

I am struggling to install MySQL 5.7 on Windows 10 after a clean removal of MySQL 8.0. The installer defaults to the version 8.0.12, with no way for me to change it.

When I run the installer (which has the version number 5.7.23.0), I am prompted to the following screen:

[image]

... despite the fact that this installer is (supposedly) for specifically the version 5.7.

I am unfamiliar with the manual installation process, so I was wondering if someone could help me install MySQL 5.7 on my PC (preferably all the other MySQL products such as the Connector and the Workbench as well). I've been trying to follow the instructions on the official documentation, but I stopped because I had no idea what I was doing.

Comment: Error is clear enough. `The selected path already exists.` Please check the given path. You may have tried to install or installed it before.

Comment: you may have already tried to install on given path. remove that folder from your directroy and click next and finish.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Oh. I was wondering why it would complain since I'm trying to install 5.7.23, not 8.0.12. I deleted the folders and now it's installing... But it's installing 5.7.23 server along with 8.0.12 Connector and etc. Is that version mismatch ok?

Answer (score 0):

I removed my MySQL 8.0.11 installation
Then I removed all the MySQL folders in the program and data folders
I disabled the gateway
Then started the installer for version 5.7.24 and that was oke.
First download all requirements and install them first
Then the installation was done. At the Installation screen, the status was ready to download, but I ignored it first and then I enabled the gateway again and the installation was fine.

At the installation screen it was clearly that version 5.7 would be installed. It only installed some 8.0 products (like the Shell, Router, connectors etc).

After checking, i've got Workbench 8 but MySQL 5.7.24